# Tensorflow variable initialization in a loop

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying a Tensorflow example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0, name='x')
model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as session:
    for i in range(5):
        session.run(model)
        x = x + 1
        print(session.run(x))
```

But the output is unexpected. I expected it to output:

```
1 1 1 1 1
```

BUt the actual output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Why is this? session.run(model) will initialize variable each time, is this statement correct?

Comment: Good question. Depends on the implementation. It seems valid to me that the initialization is done only once in a session.

Answer (score 2):

> session.run(model) will initialize variable each time

That is correct. The issue is that each time `x = x + 1` a new addition is created in the graph, which explains the results you obtain.

Graph after the first iteration:

[image]

After the second iteration:

[image]

After the third iteration:

[image]

After the fourth iteration:

[image]

After the fifth iteration:

[image]

The code I use, mostly taken from Yaroslav Bulatov's answer in [How can I list all Tensorflow variables a node depends on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42257015/395857):

```
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def children(op):
  return set(op for out in op.outputs for op in out.consumers())

def get_graph():
  """Creates dictionary {node: {child1, child2, ..},..} for current
  TensorFlow graph. Result is compatible with networkx/toposort"""

  ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
  return {op: children(op) for op in ops}

def plot_graph(G):
    '''Plot a DAG using NetworkX'''        
    def mapping(node):
        return node.name
    G = nx.DiGraph(G)
    nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping, copy=False)
    nx.draw(G, cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'), with_labels = True)
    plt.show()


x = tf.Variable(0, name='x')
model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as session:
    for i in range(5):
        session.run(model)
        x = x + 1
        print(session.run(x))

        plot_graph(get_graph())
```

Comment: Would you like to add a few comments after each graph?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you have to initialize it inside the loop as such

```py
import tensorflow as tf

for i in range(5):
    X = tf.Variable(0, name='x')
    model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(model)
        X += 1
        print(X.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session.run(model)
```

does initialize variables each time (as it calls `model = tf.global_variables_initializer()`),
but the value of `x` which is to be used for initialisation is incremented by `1` for each entry into the loop. For example,

for `i=0`, `x` is initialised with the value it possesses at that instance, i.e. `0`. When `i=1`, `x` has been incremented to `1`, and that is the value which the initialiser will use, and so on.